Downloading files larger than 2gb via web api
I have an API that I'm connecting to when downloading a file from our website (Angular).  The user clicks the link and the website shows the download progress then the browser shows the Downloads window once complete.  All this works well until the file being downloaded is larger than 2gb.  From my research, this is a limitation to File.ReadAllBytes().  I have looked at many articles including:
Download file with WebClient or HttpClient?
Efficiently Streaming Large HTTP Responses With HttpClient
Here's the code that works:
Get Endpoint
public IHttpActionResult Get(string data)
{
    return Functions.GetFile(data, Request);
}

GetFile() Function
    public static IHttpActionResult GetFile(string data, HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        //Get data from secured string.
        SecuredString securedString = new SecuredString(data);
        Enums.FileActionType fileActionType = securedString["fileActionType"].ToEnum<Enums.FileActionType>();
        string customerCode = securedString["customerCode"];
        string fileName = securedString["fileName"];
        string filePathWithName = securedString["filePathWithName"];
        string fileFullPath = $"{Constants.BasePath}";
        string tempFile = $"{Constants.TempFolderPath}{fileName}";

        try
        {
            //Get folder structure based on download type.
            switch (fileActionType)
            {
                case Enums.FileActionType.Video:
                    string videoFilePath = securedString["filePath"];
                    fileFullPath += $"{videoFilePath}{fileName}";
                    break;

                case Enums.FileActionType.CBI:
                case Enums.FileActionType.Manual:
                case Enums.FileActionType.Report:
                    fileFullPath += filePathWithName;
                    break;

                case Enums.FileActionType.ProductDocument:
                    //Normally the path comes from here but I'm just hard coding it to make it easier to read.
                    //string filePath = securedString["filePath"];
                    fileFullPath = $"https://localhost:44347/asc/customers/public/files/productABC/{fileName}";
                    break;
            }

            //converting the file into bytes array.
            var dataBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileFullPath);

            //add bytes to memory stream.
            var dataStream = new MemoryStream(dataBytes);

            //Create new result and return it.
            return new FileDownloadResult(dataStream, request, fileName);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw (e);
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }

As it is above, I click on the link, the file downloads and shows up in my Downloads folder and the browser indicates that a file has been downloaded, just as expected.
So after reading several articles, I've come to the conclusion that large files need to be handled in chunks.  Here's my attempt at doing such (I don't assume any of this is correct as I was just trying different examples I found):
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(string data)
{
    int bufferSize = 8192;
    string fileName = "productABC_documentation.zip"; //~119MB
    string tempFile = $@"C:\NoSyncData\files\productABC\{fileName}";         
    string url = $"https://localhost:44347/asc/customers/public/files/productABC/{fileName}";

    try
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            using (Stream stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(),
                    fileStream = new FileStream(tempFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize, true))
            {
                int bytesRead;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                while ((bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    await fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                return new FileDownloadResult(stream, Request, fileName);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Throw error on any exception.
        string message = Functions.BuildErrorMessage("There was an error downloading the file.", e);
        throw new Exception("There was an error downloading the file." + Environment.NewLine + message);
    }
    finally
    {
            
    }
}

Here is the FileDownloadResult class:
public class FileDownloadResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    string fileName;
    Stream fileStream;
    HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage;
    HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage;

    public FileDownloadResult(Stream data, HttpRequestMessage request, string filename)
    {
        fileStream = data;
        httpRequestMessage = request;
        fileName = filename;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        httpResponseMessage = httpRequestMessage.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        httpResponseMessage.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

        return Task.FromResult(httpResponseMessage);
    }
}

When I run the API and website locally, I can click the file link and I can watch it download into the tempFile location C:\NoSyncData\files\productABC\ completely but the browser doesn't open the Downloads window and the file does not appear in the Downloads folder.  I'm assuming I can only write to the tempFile location because it's running locally.  I don't think an API can specify where to place a file on the client (I could be wrong but I'm not aware that it can).  How can I make it so when I click the link, the browser shows it being downloaded into the Downloads folder?

I'm unclear what Task<IHttpActionResult> Get is supposed to do. Why is it writing it to a temp file which is never re-read, and why are you reusing an already read stream from the response? What exactly is that function supposed to do, other than proxy through a request, why can you not just request from localhost:44347/ directly? "I have an API that I'm connecting to when downloading a file from our website (Angular)." what does that mean? Please explain your setup better, and explain who is the server and who is the client, and what the end resut is supposed to be.

The Get endpoint has been reduced to cut out the unnecessary code for this post.  It's supposed to take the data parameter (an encrypted string) and get the file and path to be downloaded.  I simply removed it and put it in the fileName and url variables instead.  I'll edit the post to explain a bit more.

What was happening in the original code was that File.ReadAllBytes(fileFullPath) was caching the data in your download folder.
In your new code, you have a number of issues:

You are doing return new FileDownloadResult(stream, Request, fileName); which is wrong because the HTTP stream has already been read. It should have been return new FileDownloadResult(fileStream, Request, fileName);
You need to seek back to the beginning of the stream using fileStream.Position = 0;.
The read loop is not necessary as you could have just done await stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);

However, that is all still going to cause caching to a file. You need instead to stream the HTTP response stream directly through to your FileDownloadResult.

In this particular case, do not use using otherwise the stream will be disposed before it's been read. Instead dispose in the catch.
Use a cancellationToken where possible.
Do not recreate the HttpClient every time, instead cache in a static field or use IHttpClientFactory injection.
Add the e exception object as an InnerException to your own exception. Or just use throw. Do not use throw e;.

private HttpClient _client;

public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(string data, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    string fileName = "productABC_documentation.zip"; //~119MB
    string url = $"https://localhost:44347/asc/customers/public/files/productABC/{fileName}";

    // do not dispose with `using`
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
    Stream stream  = null;
    try
    {
        response = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        // do not dispose with `using`
        stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(cancellationToken);
        return new FileDownloadResult(stream, request, fileName);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        stream?.Dispose();
        response?.Dispose();
        string message = Functions.BuildErrorMessage("There was an error downloading the file.", e);
        throw new Exception("There was an error downloading the file." + Environment.NewLine + message, e);
    }
}

Why exactly you are proxying through from localhost is unclear. Is it the same ASP.NET server or is it a different one? What extra processing does this function do that you don't have if you just call localhost:44347 anyway?

Thank you for your answer.  I'm getting an error from the browser (in the console, not in the API) when trying to download a 2.9gb file "Array Buffer Allocation Failed".

Are you typing the URL directly into the address bar, or are you using some Javascript to do this?

It's a direct call from a link.  I can put the url into the address bar but I get the same result.  What's odd is if I watch the progress in the Network tab of the browser, I can see it get all the way to 2967MB and then it throws that error.  I would think if it was a size issue then it would have thrown the error right at 2GB.
